# How to align text to the right of the screen and has background color?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a text to display on the right hand side of the screen. It needs a background color of black and the background width should not extend the whole width of the screen and only the text, which I achieved by doing `display: block`. Now I cant seem to align the text to the right of the screen. I tried doing `text-align: right` but nothing happens.

```css
.mytext {
background: black;
color: white;
display: inline;
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p class="mytext">hello hello</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align` should be applied on the parent, not the element it self.

Also it will only have an effect on inline level elements (inline and inline-block), and will only be visible if there's space for it to move the element.

```css
div {
  text-align: right;
}

.mytext {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="mytext">hello hello</p>
</div>
```

or you could use floats, but i wouldn't recommend it since it's achievable using text-align property, and we all know how weird floats are.

Answer (score 1):

You could `float` the text instead?

```css
.mytext {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<p class="mytext">hello hello</p>
```